# Data marts - to create multiple database or consolidate in one?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, dimensional-modeling

Take this as an example (image taken from Google):
[image]

All data pipeline diagrams show that there are multiple data marts for each different business units or specific workscope (in this case, `Purchasing`, `Sales`, `Inventory`).

Given the two options below:

Option A:

```
car-db
 |_ Databases
    |_ carDataMarts
       |_ dbo.fact_purchase_x
       |_ dbo.dim_purchase_y
       |_ dbo.dim_purchase_z
       |_ dbo.fact_sales_x
       |_ dbo.dim_sales_y
       |_ dbo.dim_sales_z
       |_ dbo.fact_inventory_x
       |_ dbo.dim_inventory_y
       |_ dbo.dim_inventory_z
```

Option B

```
car-db
 |_ Databases
    |_ car_purchase_DataMart
       |_ dbo.fact_purchase_x
       |_ dbo.dim_purchase_y
       |_ dbo.dim_purchase_z
    |_ car_sales_DataMart
       |_ dbo.fact_sales_x
       |_ dbo.dim_sales_y
       |_ dbo.dim_sales_z
    |_ car_inventory_DataMarts
       |_ dbo.fact_inventory_x
       |_ dbo.dim_inventory_y
       |_ dbo.dim_inventory_z
```

1. How will the diagram translate to the actual implementation of data marts (option A or B)?
2. There should be some kind of differences in term of performance or usability between option A and B, if so what are these differences?

P.S: Using MS SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep in mind, this example from Google is in regards to a data warehouse / OLAP design implementation, which is ideal for reporting (usually of the aggregative nature), especially to make ad-hoc reporting most flexible to the consumers. But it's not an ideal design for an OLTP system if you were planning to build applications on top of it that can read individual rows and write data back to the Tables.

> 1. How will the diagram translate to the actual implementation of data marts (option A or B)?

The diagram *technically* translates into option B because it is using the symbol for a database, for each data mart. But I don't necessarily agree with this type of design for this specific example, where data will probably have strong relations between those databases.

`Sales`, `Purchasing`, and `Inventory` are usually strongly related, and have a high likelihood of wanting to be reported on concurrently, even from an OLAP perspective. While separating things into different databases isn't necessarily a bad thing, it just doesn't make a lot of sense with such strongly related database objects, and there are a few minor drawbacks of doing so in SQL Server.

One drawback is that you need to manage security separately in each database, and will need to appropriately set it up for the users who would need to query objects from multiple domains, e.g. `Sales` vs `Purchasing`, at the same time. Because even if you created a View in the `Sales` database that referenced Tables from the `Purchase` database, no one would be able to use that View unless they had read permissions in **both** databases. There's an alternative solution that *fixes* this, called [cross-database ownership chaining](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52875.sql-server-exploring-cross-database-ownership-chaining.aspx) but it's generally highly recommended against to enable this feature.

Instead I would personally put these 3 domains (`Sales`, `Purchasing`, and `Inventory`) in the same database but each under their own schema like so:

```
car-db
  |_ Database
    |_ carDataMarts
       |_ purchasing.fact_x
       |_ purchasing.dim_y
       |_ purchasing.dim_z
       |_ sales.fact_x
       |_ sales.dim_y
       |_ sales.dim_z
       |_ inventory.fact_x
       |_ inventory.dim_y
       |_ inventory.dim_z
```

This allows you to organize things by their domain, and you *can* manage permissions at a granular level by domain on the schema if you wanted, but you don't need to do so and can manage them all together at the database level too.

> 2. There should be some kind of differences in term of performance or usability between option A and B, if so what are these differences?

I don't believe there's any differences performance-wise between any of the aforementioned options (my suggestion using schemas being option C). SQL Server doesn't really care if you query objects across databases or schemas, in that regard. And usability-wise I would defer back to what I discussed regarding managing permissions, in my earlier paragraphs.